# more greasy food

Tags: ambiguity, comparative

a. I eat more greasy food than he does.

Is that sentence ambiguous?

I think it could mean

1. I eat food that is more greasy than he food he eats.
   and
2. I eat a bigger amount of greasy food than he does.

Is that correct?

Comment: There's [not much to choose](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+greasier%2Cis+more+greasy&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) between the one-word and two-word comparatives for ***greasy***. But *in practice* the intended sense would probably be contextually obvious (or of no consequence), and personally I think the precise intonation should make a difference (slight stress on ***greasy*** for sense #1, or stress on ***more*** for sense #2).

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence "I eat more greasy food that he does" is not ambiguous. Where I live, when people say that, it means that you eat a larger amount of greasy food than he does.

If the food you eat has more grease than the food he eats, then you say, "I eat greasier food than he does."

The comparative form of greasy is greasier. The superlative form is greasiest. See [The Titi Tudorancea Bulletin](https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/greasy.htm#:%7E:text=Greasy%20(greasier%2C%20greasiest)).

Comment: Just because the one-word form ***greasier*** does exist doesn't mean you can unambiguously rule out ***more greasy*** being used with exactly the same meaning. OP's text ***is*** ambiguous - it's just that in the exact context here, you could in principle use the one-word form to eliminate the ambiguity (for ***one*** of the possible senses).

Comment: I edited my answer to insert that this is how we speak where I live. I am not basing it merely on some written rule like you suggest but on the verbal tradition of a native English-speaking community.

Comment: I'm guessing that means you're American then. As a Brit, I just took it at face value when Google NGrams showed prevalence about equal for the two forms (but fairly obviously OP's sense #1 would be *vastly* more common as regards intended *meaning*). But when I check the US/UK corpuses separately, it seems that Americans are ***much more likely*** to use the one-word form. Hence the alternative two-word form sounds somewhat "marked" to Americans, so they naturally cast about for some plausible semantic distinction (in which context, OP's suggestion #2 is the obvious candidate alternative).

Comment: I am a Canadian.

Comment: Thank you both so much. Every time native speakers disagree about how to reply to a question, I tell myself that I have asked a good question! There are different varieties of English. It is the same with every language. Discovering the differences is fun. Thanks again.

Comment: It certainly looks as though there's a degree of "regional variation" here. The underlying *principle* here works for me as well though. If we switch to single-syllable ***hot*** I would make exactly this same distinction between *He eats **hotter / more hot** food than me* (where I'd always assume ***hotter*** for "spicier", ***more hot*** for "greater quantity").  I've removed my downvote, and I you could find a way of briefly introducing that principle into the answer (so it's not *just* dealing with the specific case of 2-syllable ***greasy***), I would enthusiastically ***upvote***.